# Parameters Date List Power BI to filter out values / Exclude value from table in M code?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Hi I want to exclude a list of date in format textin Power BI M query/code ,
The user can therefore enter a list of date to filter that out of the table in the column ACTUAL_DATE - Copy  :)

```
let
Portfolioname = #"Mapping-PortfolioName"[PortfolioName],
SelectDelta = @#"Mapping Columns-03 PORT TE"[Column_Name],
BqlQuery = BQL.Query("let(#report=dropna(PORT_ALL(report_name='03 PORT TE',classification_level=[" & Classification & "],dates=range(" & #"Delta Date-1" & ", "& #"Delta Date" &" , frq=D)), remove_id=true);)get(#report)for([" & Text.Combine( Portfolioname, ",") & "])preferences(addcols=all)"),
SelectedColumns = Table.SelectColumns(BqlQuery, SelectDelta),
Source = SelectedColumns,
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"ACTUAL_DATE", Order.Ascending}, {"ID", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Rounded Off" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{{"TOTAL_RISK_D_D", each Number.Round(_, 2), type number}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Rounded Off", "ACTUAL_DATE", "ACTUAL_DATE - Copy"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Duplicated Column",{{"ACTUAL_DATE - Copy", type text}}),

 

    Filterfunction = (row) => List.Contains(ExcludeDate,row[#"ACTUAL_DATE - Copy"]),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", Filterfunction)

 

    //#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([#"ACTUAL_DATE - Copy"] <> ExcludeDate))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"

 

//example value "29-08-23", "28-08-23"
```

Error received :
cannot convert value to type list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample to filter out and remove based on list of items, date based

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type date}}),
ExcludeList = List.Transform(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ExcludeListRangeName"]}[Content][Column1], each Date.From(_)),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each not List.ContainsAny(ExcludeList,{[Column1]}))
in #"Filtered Rows"
```

[image]